# Controls wiggeling wround

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to create a dynamic circular progress bar that can be used for example in a tree while a TreeItem is loading.

**Unfortunalety the control is not really running smooth.**

[image: preview]

This is 16x16, 16x32, 32x16 and 32x32 at 400% size.
At the beginning of the gif its running a bit laggy thats because of the capturing tool.
As you can see the circles are wiggeling around a bit, thats what I want to remove.

This is my custom control:

Code-Behind:

```
/// <summary>
///     Interaction logic for CircularProgressBar.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class CircularProgressBar
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DeferedVisibilityProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(DeferedVisibility), typeof(bool),
        typeof(CircularProgressBar), new PropertyMetadata
        {
            PropertyChangedCallback = OnDeferedVisibilityChanged,
            DefaultValue = false
        });

    private readonly (Ellipse, int)[] _circlesWithOffset;
    private Stopwatch _stopwatch;


    public CircularProgressBar()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof(CircularProgressBar);
        _circlesWithOffset = new[] {(C0, 0), (C1, 1), (C2, 2), (C3, 3), (C4, 4), (C5, 5), (C6, 6), (C7, 7), (C8, 8)};
    }


    #region Animation

    private void Start()
    {
        //Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait;
        if(_stopwatch == null)
            _stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        _stopwatch.Start();
        CompositionTarget.Rendering += CompositionTarget_Rendering;
    }


    private void Stop()
    {
        //Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Arrow;
        _stopwatch.Stop();
        CompositionTarget.Rendering += CompositionTarget_Rendering;
    }


    private void CompositionTarget_Rendering(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _circlesWithOffset.ToList().ForEach(x => SetCircle(x.Item1, x.Item2));
    }


    private void SetCircle(Ellipse circle, int offset)
    {
        var posOnCircle = _stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds * Math.PI - Math.PI / 5 * offset;
        var halfWidth = (Width - circle.Width) / 2;
        var halfHeight = (Height - circle.Height) / 2;
        circle.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, halfWidth + Math.Sin(posOnCircle) * halfWidth);
        circle.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, halfHeight + -Math.Cos(posOnCircle) * halfHeight);
    }


    private void HandleUnloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Stop();
    }


    private void HandleVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var isVisible = (bool)e.NewValue;
        if(isVisible)
            Start();
        else
            Stop();
    }

    #endregion Animation

    #region Visibility

    public bool DeferedVisibility
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(DeferedVisibilityProperty);
        set => SetValue(DeferedVisibilityProperty, value);
    }

    [Obsolete("Please use DeferedVisibility")]
    public new Visibility Visibility
    {
        get => base.Visibility;
        set => base.Visibility = value;
    }


    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        OnDeferedVisibilityChanged();
    }


    private static void OnDeferedVisibilityChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((CircularProgressBar)d).OnDeferedVisibilityChanged();
    }


    private void OnDeferedVisibilityChanged()
    {
        if(DeferedVisibility)
        {
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Visible", true);
#pragma warning disable 618
            Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
#pragma warning restore 618
        } else
        {
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Collapsed", true);
#pragma warning disable 618
            Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
#pragma warning restore 618
        }
    }

    #endregion Visibility
}
```

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.Views.Controls.Util.CircularProgressBar"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:util="clr-namespace:MyProject.Views.Controls.Util"
             Background="Transparent"
             IsVisibleChanged="HandleVisibleChanged">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <util:PercentageValueConverter x:Key="PercentageValueConverter"
                                       Scaling="0.2" />
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
          Background="Transparent"
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Canvas RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                Unloaded="HandleUnloaded">
            <Ellipse x:Name="C0"
                     SnapsToDevicePixels="False"
                     Width="{Binding Width,
                             Mode=OneWay,
                             Converter={StaticResource PercentageValueConverter},
                             RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                     Height="{Binding Height,
                             Mode=OneWay,
                             Converter={StaticResource PercentageValueConverter},
                             RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                     Stretch="Fill"
                     Fill="Black"
                     Opacity="0.9" />
            <Ellipse x:Name="C1"
                     SnapsToDevicePixels="False"
                     Width="{Binding Width,
                             Mode=OneWay,
                             Converter={StaticResource PercentageValueConverter},
                             RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                     Height="{Binding Height,
                             Mode=OneWay,
                             Converter={StaticResource PercentageValueConverter},
                             RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                     Stretch="Fill"
                     Fill="Black"
                     Opacity="0.8" />
            <Ellipse x:Name="C2"
                     SnapsToDevicePixels="False"
                     Width="{Binding Width,
                             Mode=OneWay,
                             Converter={StaticResource PercentageValueConverter},
                             RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                     Height="{Binding Height,
                             Mode=OneWay,
                             Converter={StaticResource PercentageValueConverter},
                             RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                     Stretch="Fill"
                     Fill="Black"
                     Opacity="0.7" />
            <Ellipse x:Name="C3"
                     SnapsToDevicePixels="False"
                     Width="{Binding Width,
                             Mode=OneWay,
                             Converter={StaticResource PercentageValueConverter},
                             RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                     Height="{Binding Height,
                             Mode=OneWay,
                             Converter={StaticResource PercentageValueConverter},
                             RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                     Stretch="Fill"
                     Fill="Black"
                     Opacity="0.6" />
            <Ellipse x:Name="C4"
                     SnapsToDevicePixels="False"
                     Width="{Binding Width,
                             Mode=OneWay,
                             Converter={StaticResource PercentageValueConverter},
                             RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                     Height="{Binding Height,
                             Mode=OneWay,
                             Converter={StaticResource PercentageValueConverter},
                             RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                     Stretch="Fill"
                     Fill="Black"
                     Opacity="0.5" />
            <Ellipse x:Name="C5"
                     SnapsToDevicePixels="False"
                     Width="{Binding Width,
                             Mode=OneWay,
                             Converter={StaticResource PercentageValueConverter},
                             RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                     Height="{Binding Height,
                             Mode=OneWay,
                             Converter={StaticResource PercentageValueConverter},
                             RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                     Stretch="Fill"
                     Fill="Black"
                     Opacity="0.4" />
            <Ellipse x:Name="C6"
                     SnapsToDevicePixels="False"
                     Width="{Binding Width,
                             Mode=OneWay,
                             Converter={StaticResource PercentageValueConverter},
                             RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                     Height="{Binding Height,
                             Mode=OneWay,
                             Converter={StaticResource PercentageValueConverter},
                             RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                     Stretch="Fill"
                     Fill="Black"
                     Opacity="0.3" />
            <Ellipse x:Name="C7"
                     SnapsToDevicePixels="False"
                     Width="{Binding Width,
                             Mode=OneWay,
                             Converter={StaticResource PercentageValueConverter},
                             RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                     Height="{Binding Height,
                             Mode=OneWay,
                             Converter={StaticResource PercentageValueConverter},
                             RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                     Stretch="Fill"
                     Fill="Black"
                     Opacity="0.2" />
            <Ellipse x:Name="C8"
                     SnapsToDevicePixels="False"
                     Width="{Binding Width,
                             Mode=OneWay,
                             Converter={StaticResource PercentageValueConverter},
                             RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                     Height="{Binding Height,
                             Mode=OneWay,
                             Converter={StaticResource PercentageValueConverter},
                             RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                     Stretch="Fill"
                     Fill="Black"
                     Opacity="0.1" />
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The converter is only there to set the diameter of the circles to 20% of the size of the control.

This is how to use the control anywhere

```
<util:CircularProgressBar Grid.Row="1"
                          DeferedVisibility="True"
                          Width="32"
                          Height="32" />
```

As you can see the circles position gets updated with the CompositionTarget.Rendering event.

I already tried setting SnapsToDevicePixels to false but that didn't change anything. For the position calculating there is used double so there shouldn't be any rounding inaccuracies.

Comment: take a look [here](https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/blob/master/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.ProgressBar.xaml). I'm not that good with animations, so that link is only help I can give. I use this themes a lot and they are very smooth. If not, you can always find a gif that looks like what you got there and just play it

Comment: Is there any particular reason for you to do it like this? Rotating canvas all together with a RotateTrannsform would be much easier and would provide the same effect. You would only need to animate the rotation angle with a DoubleAnimation then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer may not resolve your problem with the current code and is rather a Suggestion. The `XAML` has some neat features and used properly, you can achieve a lot with little effort.

Example: You could define a `Style` for an `UIElement` which sets the position of an `Ellipse`, preferably on a Startposition with an initial Rotation. Then Add Elements with this `Style` into some kind of Container and rotate the whole container to make it look like the single `Ellipse`s are moving. Ideally use a Container which handles the scaling of the `Ellipse`.

**Style for LoadingCircles**

```
<!-- LoadingCircles Style for a Control-Element-->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Control}" x:Key="LoadingCircles">
    <!-- Set default values (can be overridden) -->
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="Tag" Value="20"/>
    <!-- Hide Control when its not enabled -->
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
    <!-- Define the lok of the Control -->
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <!-- Use ViewBox for auto-scaling -->
                <Viewbox Stretch="Fill">
                    <!-- Set Grid Size to absolute value to scale on 100% (like Circle Size = 20 -> 20%) -->
                    <Grid Height="100" Width="100" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <!-- Define Template for Circle on a circular path whereas the Tag defines the initial Rotation (0 = top, 180 = bottom) -->
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentPresenter}">
                                <Setter Property="DataContext" Value="{Binding}"/>
                                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Border Height="100">
                                                <Border.LayoutTransform>
                                                    <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                                                </Border.LayoutTransform>
                                                <Ellipse Width="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Control}}" Height="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Control}}" Fill="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Control}}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                                            </Border>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </Grid.Resources>

                        <!-- Add Circles to the circular Path with their start-roation and opacity -->
                        <ContentPresenter Opacity="0.1" Tag="36"/>
                        <ContentPresenter Opacity="0.2" Tag="72"/>
                        <ContentPresenter Opacity="0.3" Tag="108"/>
                        <ContentPresenter Opacity="0.4" Tag="144"/>
                        <ContentPresenter Opacity="0.5" Tag="180"/>
                        <ContentPresenter Opacity="0.6" Tag="216"/>
                        <ContentPresenter Opacity="0.7" Tag="252"/>
                        <ContentPresenter Opacity="0.8" Tag="288"/>
                        <ContentPresenter Opacity="0.9" Tag="324"/>
                        <ContentPresenter Opacity="1" Tag="0"/>

                        <!-- Define Roation for all the Circles in the "Container" -->
                        <Grid.RenderTransform>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="0" x:Name="AngleEverything"/>
                        </Grid.RenderTransform>

                    </Grid>
                </Viewbox>

                <!-- Define Trigger when the Control is enabled -->
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
                        <!-- When set, start the "Container" rotation -->
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="Rotation">
                                <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="AngleEverything" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle" From="0" To="359" Duration="00:00:03"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <!-- when unset, stop the "Container" rotation -->
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <StopStoryboard Storyboard.TargetName="Rotation"/>
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                        <!-- Show control when it is enabled (otherwise hide, see Setter at the top) -->
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Notes**

The `Size` of the moving Circles is set with the `Tag` `Property` as percent (20 corresponds to 20%).

The `Color` of the Circles is set with the `Foreground` `Property`.

The `Visibility` of the Control is handled with the `IsEnabled` `Property`. When set to `False` the LoadingCircles are hidden.

**Usage Example**

```
<!-- LoadingCircles with 15% size and purple color -->
<Control Style="{DynamicResource LoadingCircles}" IsEnabled="{Binding YourSource}" Foreground="Purple" Tag="15" ... />
```

**Personal Note**

As you can see, it runs smoothly without the need of a `CustomControl`or any code-behind (and it is a little bit customizable). I strongly suggest you to take a closer look at the `XAML` features to get efficient results.

Comment: Nice solution, it works fine but I'm getting `System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=Tag; DataItem=null; target element is 'RotateTransform' (HashCode=49755886); target property is 'Angle' (type 'Double')` sometimes. Any idea why i get this?

Comment: @horotab This is fairly common in WPF. Sometimes when an `Element` with a relativesource is built, it fails to find the Parent and produces this error. Afterwards it find the parent and works as expected. You can ignore those errors when the code works as expected AND there are no blue squiggly lines in the Design-Mode.

Comment: If you want to know in detail whats happening with this `Binding` add `xmlns:diag="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"` to the `Namespace`s and change the `Angle` `Binding` to `Angle="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentPresenter}, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"`. The Error will still occur, but you can see that the `Binding`s are resolved successfully.